# Add fragments to scroll view

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, scrollview

I am trying to add fragments to a scrollview. I am dynamically creating the fragments and adding it. But its not working for me, here is my sample code

```
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
        {
            FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
            scroller.addView(frame);
            frame.setId(i+10000);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.leftMargin = 10;
            frame.setLayoutParams(params);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(i + 10000,ItemFragment.init(i));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            i++;
        }
```

But on second iteration of the loop app crashes. Whats going wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, It is very mistake an approach. You should use Android viewpager. You can research following http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Ok, I got the concept wrong. Thanks. I am already using view pager, but i need something that flips through the pages very fast, with View pager only one view is changed per swipe. Do you think of any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ScrollView can only contain one child view. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html):

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a ScrollView as the host. In your situation it doesn't seem the best solution as @stkent mentioned.

If you want to use a scrollview (there can be good reasons), you have to be sure you only have one single fragment at a time within the scrollview. If not, the scrollview will crash because it contains more than one child. Therefore, don't use `add()` the second time and don't use `replace()`. Since the latest version (2022?) of the fragment manager `replace()` will add a new fragment first before removing the old one. This will crash the scrollview too.

Remove the old fragment first (`remove()`), then add the new one.